# Azure Functions Host keys Resetting Automatically

Tags: azure

We have a Function app hosted on Azure which contains multiple functions within it.
The Function app has a common Host key.

We had issues recently the Host Keys is Reset/Deleted  automatically. Due to which the applications calling these Api's errors out and does not go through.
I did not find any information taking about this issue and what needs to be done to fix this.
Any help will be appreciate untill i investigate this issue at my end.

Comment: is it a brand new function or something that's being running for a while?

Comment: If you are using a pipeline to deploy your functions? If so each deployments resets the keys

Comment: What version of Azure Function?  v1, v2, v3?   Are you using deployment slots? Is this a consumption or dedicated app service plan?  The key management system and behavior differs based upon these things.

Comment: Hello Guys, Thanks for your response, So following are the information you asked for  a) To answer Thiagos Q, Its a existing function running for a while. b) To answer troy Q we are using V2 and we are not using deployment slots, it is a consumption dedicated app service plan

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with pretty much the same situation (V2/Consumption Plan) except it's a FunctionKey and not a HostKey, but I'm sure the default HostKey is also being reset. Sometimes it'll go weeks without an issue and sometimes only days. No deployments have been done in months. My guess is the issue has something to do with the consumption plan since we have Apps on a Standard plan that have never had this issue.

Comment: If you add a custom host key does it get reset too?

Comment: We experienced this and concluded it probably was Microsoft/Azure that fucked up. We contacted them and they began investigation. Hasn't happened for us since.

Comment: Do you guys find any fix on this.. I'm still facing the same challenge.