# Azure Function Keys do they expire?

Tags: azure-functions

I am planning to use azure functions with an Authorization Level=Function.

What I could not work out is if the HostKeys actually expire or renewed automatically,

I want to make sure that I am in control when to "Renew key value".

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The host key will not be expired.

Answer (score 0):

We just had a host `_master` key renew itself automatically (see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533686/azure-functions-host-keys-resetting-automatically), plus [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533686/azure-functions-host-keys-resetting-automatically) for more examples of this happening).

Unfortunately I'm having as much trouble as you with discovering whether this is a bug or a feature, and--if it's a feature--what the auto-renewal schedule looks like.